# How can i handle language changes when coming back from android recent apps

Tags: android, android-resources, onresume

I'm having a problem with an android application. My app title is internationalized. When i access the app on the language Spanish and press the home button and change the phone language to portuguese and then came back to my app by the "recent apps list" the app title does not change. It stays on spanish, instead of portuguese. Do you know any way to fix this issue?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use to like this android:label="@strings/app_name" in manifest file. and you must specify the app_name's portuguese value and spanish value in strings.xml. (of course separataly in values-es and in values-pt)

your strings.xml in values-es file

```
<string name="app_name">Spanish app name</string>
```

your strings.xml in values-pt file

```
<string name="app_name">Portuguese app name</string>
```

and your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
 android:label="@strings/app_name" 
... />
```

like this.

Comment: my AndroidManifest looks like this:
 <activity android:name="com.xx.TestActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.xx.BACKGROUND_ICON"
                android:resource="@drawable/tile_background_icon" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.xx.TITLE"
                android:resource="@string/tile_title" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.xx.SMALL_ICON"
                android:resource="@drawable/tile_small_icon" />

The string that is not being translated is the tile_title